# C# date doesnt remove leading zero for non en-us locale

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I dont want any leading zeros in front of month or day. it works fine for en-US

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d"); //"3/17/2015"
```

However for en-GB I dont want 0 in front of the month. The expected resutl is "17/3/2015" but the output i am getting is -

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d") //"17/03/2015"
```

For Japan local as well i am getting 0 before the month.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d") //"2015/03/17"
```

I am setting culture in the current thread

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(localeString);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because the day is not in the first place in right or left side so you'll find the leading zero

if you don't need that so use :

```
.ToString("yyyy/M/d")
```

or something like it with your preferred order but not only :
.`.ToString("d")`

Comment: No. Not like that. Cauz he wants the date to be display localised. So that it automatically gets changed based on the regional settings of your system

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("{0:d}")
```

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by customizing the DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern

```
string dateFormat = currCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace("dd",   "d").Replace("MM", "M").Replace("yyyy", "yy");
```

and then using it

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat);
```